# Unity Very Large 2D World - Floating point precision limits

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game about flying a spaceship to different planets and moons. Something like Kerbal Space Program but in 2d. When I go more than 100000 units from the center of the world under the transform of the rocket there would appear a message/error(Due to floating point precision limitations, it is recommended to bring the world coordinates of the gameobject within a smaller range) and the script for calculating the distance to the nearest planet would stop working and display a 0. Is there a way to make 2d worlds larger than 100000 units?

The Script for the distance to the nearest planet;

````
{
    GameObject Planet;
    Vector2 Direction;
    public float Height;
    public int HeightINT;
    public Text text;
    public bool isKM;
    void Start()
    {
        Planet = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlanetCentre");

    }


    void Update()
    {
        Direction = (Planet.transform.position - transform.position);
        RayCastHeight();

        if(Height >= 1000)
        {
            text.text = (HeightINT/1000).ToString() + " KM";

        }
        if(Height < 1000)
        {
            text.text = HeightINT.ToString() + " M";
        }
    }
    void RayCastHeight()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Direction);
        Height = (hit.distance * 5);
        HeightINT = Mathf.RoundToInt(Height);
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3d floating point precision limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879654/unity3d-floating-point-precision-limitations)

Answer (score 1):

First what comes to my mind, I wuld maybe recommend you to store your distance as `string`, and then parsing it to int. But I'm not sure, how it will all work. Hope this helps a bit.